# Automatic Sheet Calculation (Checkbox linked to cell)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a table where I've inserted some Checkboxes (Form Control) which are linked to cells that return True or False when either Checkbox is ticked.
I wrote a code that should change the cell's color according to the returned value. 
The code works fine but only when I double click the cell and validate by pressing Enter, or when I run the Sub by hitting F5 or a clicking a button. 
(I used a similar code that updates everything automatically in another project but it doesn't seem to work here)

How can I make the Sub run automatically (or the sheet update) once a checkbox is ticked?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2:Q21"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Q21")

            If cell.Value = "True" Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            ElseIf cell.Value = "False" Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I know I could use conditional formatting but this sheet will expand rapidly and I don't see myself copy-pasting hundreds of checkboxes

As the sheet will expand I think it'll be better to include a "lastRow" statement since I will be adding new rows at the bottom using a UserForm

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the part doing the coloring to a new function and call that from both the original and from the checkbox's event handler.

```
' In Sheet1 Module

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2:Q21"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ColorCells
    End If
End Sub


' In Module1 Module

Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    ColorCells
End Sub

Public Sub ColorCells()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Q21")

        If cell.Value = "True" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        ElseIf cell.Value = "False" Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**

If there are too many checkboxes than you may use the Worksheet's Calculation event handler assuming that the checkboxes have Linked Cells and some other Cell refers to their value.

```
' In Sheet1 Module

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ColorCells
End Sub
```

Note, if the checkbox does not have a Linked Cell, it won't work. If the checkbox has a Linked Cell but it is not referred to by any other cell, it won't work. This is because in these cases no recalculation will be initiated.

You can test this: Assign A1 to a Checkbox (on a new sheet), and try if the macro runs (should not), then write in A2 `=2*--A1`, and check again, now it should work.

If you want to minimize the footprint of this requirement, find an unused cell on the sheet and enter the following formula: `=INDEX(1:1048576,1,1)`. This refers to all cells but it does not require a lengthy calculation. Of course, if you want to place it into A1, you should change the `,1,1` part to something else to avoid circular references.

Comment: Hmm I was afraid one might say that.
So if there are 3000 checkboxes in the sheet I will have to call the ColorCells from every single checkbox sub?

Comment: @MikeRophone do you want the calculation to happen instantly? If not you can write a quick loop that goes over the entire sheet every so often, or when a button is pressed.

Comment: Ideally, the calculation should happen whenever anything changes within the Sheet

Comment: @MikeRophone Anything that requires recalculation, see my updated answer for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing your colouring sub at `Worksheet_Change`, put it under `Worksheet_Calculate`. Then insert the formula `=A1:Q21`(or whatever you need to cover your range) somewhere in your sheet. It will resolve to `#value` but that isn't important. This formula will force your sheet to automatically recalculate when anything within its range is changed, including the cells linked to your checkboxes. And then upon recalculate it will fire the sub that colours your cells correctly.

Comment: Or just look at @z32a7ul edit for a more complete explanation.